# How to have two methods calling each other?

Tags: f#, mutual-recursion

I'm a bit confused as to how to get two method to call each other (i.e., have `A()` call `B()` and `B()` call `A()`). It seems that F# only 'sees' the method after it's been encountered in code, so if it hasn't, it just says *value or constructor has not been defined*.

Am I missing something very basic here?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

'let rec... and...' is the syntax you seek.

```
let rec F() = 
    G()
and G() =
    F()
```

See also [Adventures in F# Co-Recursion](http://blogs.msdn.com/jomo_fisher/archive/2007/09/24/adventures-in-f-corecursion.aspx).

Comment: Best solution. However, if we need to **have A() call B() and B() call A()** then there is something wrong with our functional design. Ideally, we shouldn't encounter this situation. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ozgur imagine you want to create a JSON parser. Then you would need a function that parses lists whose elements can be objects. And you need a function that parses objects whose values can be lists. This type of recursion isn't as rare as you might think.

Answer (score 22):

Since the question is about methods, and Brian's answer is about functions, maybe it's useful to point out that you can use a similar syntax for types:

```
type A() =
    let b = new B()
    member x.MethodA() = b.MethodB()
and B() =
    member x.MethodB() = ()
```

Note also that members are 'let rec' by default (in fact I don't think they can be not recursive).

Answer (score 10):

F# 4.1 introduces [mutually recursive modules and namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/modules#module-rec-allowing-mutual-recursive-code-at-the-module-level).

These are an alternative to the `and` keyword.

```
module rec PingPong = // <------ rec keyword here.

    let pong() = 
        printfn "pong"
        ping() 

    let ping () = 
        printfn "ping"
        pong()
```

The `rec` keyword defines modules and namespaces that "allow for all contained code to be mutually recursive."

Answer (score 6):

### Functions declared via let

```
let rec a () = b ()
and b () = ()
```

These are *mutually recursive functions*.

### Methods within the same type

```
type T () =
    member t.A () = t.B()
    member t.B () = ()
```

This is trivial; it just works. *Note Abel's comment though.*

### Methods within different types

```
type TypeA () =
    member t.A (b : TypeB) = b.B()

and TypeB () =
    member b.B () = ()
```

This uses the `type ... and` syntax for *mutually recursive types*.

### Notes

Normally, `and` is only used if the calls occur in both directions. Otherwise, it may be better to re-order the declarations so that the called function comes first. It is often helpful for type-inference and readability to avoid circular dependencies, and to not imply them where they aren't used.

I propose to edit the question to either ask for functions in general, or to ask for different types (in which case I would remove the first two cases from this answer). Methods are usually considered to be a subset of functions, which is the general mathematical term. However, all F# functions are technically *CLI methods*, as that is what they are compiled to. As is, it is not clear what the question is asking for, but I assume from the accepted answer that it does not only ask for methods, as the title would imply.

Comment: On _Methods within different types_ you say it is "trivial; it just works", but there's a subtlety that's easily overlooked: when you use `inline` and/or certain member constraints it may require you to declare them in order (i.e., backward references will yield strange and hard-to-diagnose errors). See bug report [Order of members of a type is relevant](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1565)