# F# forward type declarations

Tags: syntax, f#, recursion, types, mutual-recursion

I stumbled across this problem in F#. Suppose, I want to declare two types that reference each other:

```
type firstType = 
     | T1 of secondType
     //................

type secondType =
     | T1 of firstType  
     //................
```

How do I do that, so the compiler does not generate an error?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680606/f-how-to-have-two-methods-calling-each-other

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You use 'and':

```
type firstType = 
     | T1 of secondType

and secondType =
     | T1 of firstType
```

Comment: Every time I feel something isn't elegant in F# I'm pleasantly surprised there's an elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it. It's:

```
type firstType = 
     | T1 of secondType
     //................

and secondType =
     | T1 of firstType  
     //................
```

Comment: you use the same notation for mutually recursive functions as well - in case you didn't already know that.

Answer (score 3):

The limitation is that the types have to be declared in the same file.