# how to define two types referring to each other in OCaml?

Tags: types, recursion, ocaml

The code below will report Syntax error message:

```
type 'a edge = 
  |Empty 
  |End of 'a * 'a vertex * 'a vertex and
type 'a vertex = 
  |Empty
  |Vertex of 'a * 'a edge list;;
```

How to define two types referring to each other?

Comment: This is a commonly asked question.  Here's a link to a similar one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026123/ocaml-forward-declaration

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize the forward declaration post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second `type` is not syntactically correct:

```
type 'a edge = 
  |Empty 
  |End of 'a * 'a vertex * 'a vertex
and 'a vertex = 
  |Empty
  |Vertex of 'a * 'a edge list;;
```

Comment: (The key is that you need to use `and` to define mutually recursive types.)