# F#: Entity Framework Issue With File Order

Tags: entity-framework, f#

Is there a way for two entities with foreign key relations to be represented in class files keeping in mind that F# has to have the files in order?

Say I have a User and the user has books.

```
type User(books:seq<Book>) :
  mutable _books = books

  member public x.Books
    with get() = _books
    and set bookList = _books  <- bookList


type Books(parentUser:User) : 
  mutable _parentUser = parentUser

  member public x.ParentUser
    with get() = _parentUser
    and set newParentUser = _parentUser <- newParentUser
```

Now because of how F# works, this won't compile since it's basically a circular reference.  User comes before Book therefore it doesn't know what a book is.  If I move the book class up, the opposite is true.

Is there a way around the whole "Compile in order" way that F# works or do I need to set up entities and relations in another language?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378575/f-forward-type-declarations answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to define both types in the same file using `type User ... and Books`. See the section on [Mutually Recursive Types on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233205.aspx).