# F#: Mutually recursive functions

Tags: f#, recursion, mutual-recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [[F#] How to have two methods calling each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680606/f-how-to-have-two-methods-calling-each-other)

Hello all,

I Have a scenario where I have two functions that would benefit from being mutually recursive but I'm not really sure how to do this in F#

My scenario is not as simple as the following code, but I'd like to get something similar to compile:

```
let rec f x =
  if x>0 then
    g (x-1)
  else
    x

let rec g x =
  if x>0 then
    f (x-1)
  else
    x
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378575/f-forward-type-declarations

Comment: I hesitate to mark this one as the duplicate, because the title is probably better...

Comment: @Benjol: Generally we don not *delete* duplicates with substantially different titles in order to improve searchability, but we still close them.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can also use `let` `rec` ... `and` form:

```
let rec f x =
  if x>0 then
    g (x-1)
  else
    x

and g x =
  if x>0 then
    f (x-1)
  else
    x
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 42 seconds... :-)

Comment: +1, Nice, didn't realize you could use `and` with let bindings.  I thought it's usage was restricted to `type` declarations.

Comment: It's specially useful (necessary) if you have mutually recursive types (like two DUs) and two functions that take each as an input argument.

Answer (score 3):

To get mutually recursive functions simply pass one to the other as a parameter

```
let rec f g x =
  if x>0 then
    g (x-1)
  else
    x

let rec g x =
  if x>0 then
    f g (x-1)
  else
    x
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `let rec ... and ...` construct:

```
let rec f x =
  if x>0 then
    g (x-1)
  else
    x

and g x =
  if x>0 then
    f (x-1)
  else
    x
```