# When to use `let ... in` to bind variables?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

Based on the [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/546326/7821462) of "Meaning of keyword “in” in F#":

```
let (x = 2 and y = x + 2) in
    y + x
```

This will not work the same as

```
let (x = 2 and y = x + 2)
    y + x
```

In the former case `x` is only bound after the `in` keyword. In the later case normal variable scoping rules take effect, so variables are bound as soon as they are declared.

When one need to specify bound variables with `in`, instead of binding as they are declared?

Comment: That is not even valid F#. `let` allows only one binding. And, as far as I understand, there is always `in`, but *Lightweight Syntax* allows you to omit it.

Comment: @PetSerAl it should have been `let x = 2 in y = x + 2 in y +x`, I just copied the accepted answer.

Comment: To be syntactically correct it should be `let x = 2 in let y = x + 2 in y + x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `let`/`in` like this:

```
let x = 2 in
    let y = x + 2 in
        y + x
```

F# is an expression-based language, and the code in this form reveals that. However, there is syntactic sugar built in so that you can write the same thing in a flat way that looks statement-based, but isn't really:

```
let x = 2
let y = x + 2
y + x
```

You could use `in` if you really want to stay on the same line `let x = 2 in x + 2`. However, it's very unusual to see this. In the thousands of lines of F# I've worked with I've never seen it or used it myself.

Comment: What would you do if `x` and `y` are mutually dependent?

Comment: @leftaroundabout These are just values. If they were mutually dependent wouldn't it create an infinite loop to evaluate them? If you want mutually recursive functions then you can use [`let rec`...`and`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621043/f-mutually-recursive-functions)