# F# - function order

Tags: f#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to have two methods calling each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680606/how-to-have-two-methods-calling-each-other)

I need to write 2 functions that call each other.
(with conditions inside - so they'd eventually stop)

```
let x () : int =
   ...
   if (------) then
     y num
   ...


let y () : int =
   ...
   if (------) then
     x num
   ...
```

The problem is that, as I understand it, F# evaluates functions by order of appearance.. so writing this will create compilation errors...

Is there a way to solve this problem?
So both functions will know each other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the `and` keyword for [mutually-recursive functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233232.aspx):

```
let rec x num =
   ...
   if (------) then
     y num
   ...

and y num =
   ...
   if (------) then
     x num
   ...
```